# Advantages to using foreach compared to for

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, foreach

What are the advantages to using a `forEach` loop compared to a `for` loop?

Comment: In which programming language?

Comment: Oh JavaScript, sorry i don&#39;t specify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For, foreach. For and foreach differ slightly in performance. They are approximately the same speed. But the foreach loop uses more stack space for local variables.

The for-loop is faster than the foreach-loop if the array must only be accessed once per iteration.

Source: https://www.dotnetperls.com/for-foreach

Comment: Ok tranks you, it helped me ;P